# FileUpload control viewed in IE8 doesn't allow user to enter manual path

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a page with a FileUpload control. In IE7, it allowed file/directory browsing using either the "Browse" button (which brings up a file directory dialog) or by manually typing in a file path. In IE8, the text box portion of the control seems to be disabled and only allows a file to be specified by finding it with the "Browse" button. This is not a huge problem for users who rarely enter a file path manually, but our QA team relies on manually entering file paths as part of our automated tests. Does anyone know if this can be changed?

UPDATE: This behaviour was added as a security feature in IE8 and cannot be modified.
http://www.tomsguide.com/us/internet-explorer-microsoft-security-hackers,news-1858.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need it to be changed?  You can click the `Browse` button and then manually enter the file path into the browse dialog - that dialog will accept a full path being typed (or pasted) into it.  It's just the same, but with one extra click to show the dialog, and one extra click (or `Enter`) to OK it.

Comment: I agree.  The behavior of IE8 was probably changed as a security precaution, and I doubt they will have made any way for you to get around it in your HTML.  This will just be a matter of training your QA team.

Comment: @Stripling,
You're right. Looks like it was added to IE8 as a security feature. Commencing training of QA team...

Answer (score 0):

This is very unfortunate, if anyone finds an automated solution for uploading files please post here (is it possible with celerity ?)( is it possible with watin and firefox ?).

There is a another reference+ example to the problem of IE8 and above here:

[FileUpload control viewed in IE8 doesn't allow user to enter manual path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998757/fileupload-control-viewed-in-ie8-doesnt-allow-user-to-enter-manual-path)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you can force IE8 to allow you to enter a path, but usually with the file chooser, you can type in a path and click open. (I don't have IE8 so I don't know exactly what it looks like)